# org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.NoSuchColumnFamilyException: Column family info does not exist in region TestTable

Tags: hadoop, hbase

```
hbase(main):005:0> list 'TestTable:family.*'
TABLE                                                                                                                                                                  
0 row(s) in 0.0070 seconds

=> []
hbase(main):006:0>
```

---

```
2016-07-14 18:17:29,415 INFO  [TestClient-0] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Session: 0x355e8511eb40011 closed
2016-07-14 18:17:29,416 INFO  [TestClient-0-EventThread] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down
java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedWithDetailsException: Failed 2804 actions: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.NoSuchColumnFamilyException: Column family info does not exist in region TestTable,,1468486486864.5e87c6b8eb2accd7e096475082ad2128. in table 'TestTable', {NAME => 'family', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', VERSIONS => '1', TTL => 'FOREVER', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'FALSE', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', IN_MEMORY => 'false', BLOCKCACHE => 'true'}
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.doBatchOp(RSRpcServices.java:708)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.doNonAtomicRegionMutation(RSRpcServices.java:663)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.multi(RSRpcServices.java:2050)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:32393)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2127)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor.consumerLoop(RpcExecutor.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$1.run(RpcExecutor.java:108)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I cannot understand , and I cannot use JAVA

I'm trying to stress test to HBase use PerformanceEvaluation. But it has been reported to this error. This error is told me `TestTable` does not exist.But I'm sure that `TestTable` is exist ! I cannot understand this notice.

Comment: Some details on what you are doing and what you are trying to achieve would be useful in order to help you.

Comment: @JackrenChen ```list``` command is just for tables, maybe you can try to run ```list TestTable*```, and could you add the command which produces the err?